# Vanity URL while Loop with PDO Select and Insert not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to implement a simple mysql insert that takes the user's first name ($first_name) and the user's last name ($last_name) and inserts them into my users table (url) column. This is very much like Quora and Facebook...www.facebook.com/Michael.Jackson.32 for example.

My while loop is below and I wish I knew the error but when I execute the code, my server just keeps going and eventually timeouts.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
//Store Vanity URL
$user_id_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name");
$user_id_sql->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name , ':last_name' => $last_name));
$user_search_results = $user_id_sql->rowCount();

if($user_search_results == "0") {
    $vanity = $first_name.'.'.$last_name;
    $insert_vanity_url = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (url) VALUES (:vanity) WHERE uid = :uid");
    $insert_vanity_url->execute(array(':vanity'=>$vanity , ':uid'=>$uid));
}
else {
    $var1 = "bad";
    $i = "1";
    while($var1 == "bad") {
        $user_id_sql_two = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name");
        $user_id_sql_two->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name , ':last_name' => $last_name));
        $user_search_results_two = $user_id_sql_two->rowCount();
        if($user_search_results_two == "0") {
            $vanity = $first_name.'.'.$last_name.$i;]
            $insert_vanity_url = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (url) VALUES (:vanity) WHERE uid = :uid");
            $insert_vanity_url->execute(array(':vanity'=>$vanity, ':uid'=>$uid));
            $var1 = "good";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, can you please make sure your code is formatted? I've submitted an edit, so this one will be ok.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't know I was supposed to format like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem (well the specific problem):

This query:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name
```

does exactly what you think it does, gets all the users with that first and last name. The first time it is used, if no user like that exists, you add the user and the vanity and go on your way.

However, if such a user does exists, as determined by `rowCount()`, you go into that loop.

That loop contains the same query, checking to see if there are any users with that first and last name. But the only reason you are in this block is because there are users that match the query.

The general logic here is:

1. If such a user does not exist, create them.
2. If such a user does exists, loop until it doesn't exist anymore.

What you should probably do is generate the basic vanity, then check for *its* existence in the table, then you can check your fallback ones, generating a new vanity each loop until it doesn't exist (this is actually not that good a way of doing it, but better would require more significant changes).

There is actually a lot more to improve with your code, but this is not Code Review, so I will hold my tongue.

Comment: The problem was actually the insert rather than an update statement.

Comment: Are you sure? Actually try that code you posted. There is definitely an infinite loop, since you don't make any modifications to any variables based on $i, except inside the condition (which you will never get to because of aforementioned lack of changing).

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention that. I took your advice and create the vanity url first then search for it before the update statement. Then I add the $i to it if it already exists in the DB.